# Function each() is depreciated, but foreach loop isn't converting correctly

Tags: php

This site website I've inherited is being transferred to a PHP 7.0 environment, and after running a compatibility checker, as it's WP, I've found a couple errors where an .each() is used in place of a foreach() loop. However, I've never used an .each() loop and after looking at some documentation and stackoverflows, I am just not wrapping my head around converting it. I am wondering if someone could help me clear this up. From looking at the code, the only thing I'm really seeing is that `$k` is an indication of the array position? So, I thought maybe if I tried to set it to a number, and let it increment?

### Original Code

```
public function _sanitize_data_array($submited_data)
    {
        $in = array(&$submited_data);
        while ( list($k,$v) = each($in) ) {
            foreach ( $in as $key => $val ) {
                if ( !is_array($val) ) {
                    $in[$k][$key] = trim(stripslashes($val));
                    $in[$k][$key] = wp_kses($in[$k][$key], $allowed_html=array());
                    $in[$k][$key] = esc_attr($in[$k][$key]);
                    $in[$k][$key] = trim($in[$k][$key]);

                    continue;
                };
                if ( is_array($val) ) {
                    $in[$k][$key] = array_filter($val);
                };
                $in[] =& $in[$k][$key];
            };
        };

        unset($in);
        return $submited_data;
    }

public function scroll()
    {
        $raw_data = $_POST;
        $data = $this->_sanitize_data_array($raw_data);

        $properties = $this->_get_properties($data);

        $prop_str = implode('', $properties);

        $response_code = ( count( $properties ) > 0 ) ? '1' : '-1';

        $response['code'] = $response_code;
        $response['properties'] = $prop_str ;
        $response['next_page'] = $this->next_page;
        die(json_encode($response));

    }
```

### My Attempt

```
public function _sanitize_data_array($submited_data)
    {
        $in = array(&$submited_data);
        $k = 1;
        foreach ( $in as $key => $val ) {
            if ( !is_array($val) ) {
                $in[$k][$key] = trim(stripslashes($val));
                $in[$k][$key] = wp_kses($in[$k][$key], $allowed_html=array());
                $in[$k][$key] = esc_attr($in[$k][$key]);
                $in[$k][$key] = trim($in[$k][$key]);

                continue;
            };
            if ( is_array($val) ) {
                $in[$k][$key] = array_filter($val);
            };
            $in[] =& $in[$k][$key];
            $k++;
        };

        unset($in);
        return $submited_data;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like code that should be ported. It should be destroyed and rewritten from spec. From a quick look, it seems all `_sanitize_data_array` really does is `return array(array_filter($submitted_data));` (at least when $submitted_data is an array, which $_POST always should be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The real issue while trying to alter this code will not come from the** `$k` but from the line

```
 $in[] =& $in[$k][$key];.
```

The `while` loop use the array `$in` as a kind of queue .This is a common implementation of recursion without using recursive function.
Only the `each` combined to a `while/for/do while` loop  could allow this not the foreach. 
My only suggestion is to ignore the warning or to use a recursive function .If you fear the day the each function will be removed,no worries an each function is too simple to build:

```
   if(!function_exists('each')){
            function each(&$array){
                if(is_array($array)){
                    $key=key($array);
                    if($key!==null&&$key!==false){
                        next($array);
                        return array($array[$key],$key);
                    }
                    return false;   
                }elseif(is_object($array)&&key_exists('Traversable',class_implements($array))){

                    if($array->valid()){
                        $current=$array->current();
                        $key=$array->key();
                        $array->next($array);
                        return array($current,$key);
                    }
                    return false;   
                }
                return false;   
            }
    }
```

Comment: Good one, I didn't see the recursion wasn't going to work with a foreach.

Comment: Thank you Elementary, I will ignore the warning for now, but also as a test, try this bit of code. Unfortunately the original developer was creating an import for data of a SQL merge from another Database, but with no comments or documentation, so I can only really speculate. I will accept the answer if this works!

Comment: My custom each function really works... Don't forget to mark your question as solved...

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting what's inside the loops, you have to substitute the **while** loop that uses each to assign the **key** of each element of the `$in` array to `$k` with a **foreach** loop equivalent.

```
while ( list($k,$v) = each($in) ) {
    foreach ( $in as $key => $val ) {
       // Some code here
    };
};
```

It should look like this:

```
foreach ( $in as $k => $v ) {
    foreach ( $in as $key => $val ) {
        // Some code here
    };
};
```

In the original code the **while** loop is taking the **key** and **value** of the first element of the array, assigning it to the variables `$k` and `$v`, moving the cursor of the array to the next element and evaluating the code inside the block. It repeats until the aren't elements left. You can do the same with **foreach** as showed before.